# "See you Monday" vs "See you on Monday"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I have seen native speakers use both variations.

> See you Monday.

and

> See you on Monday.

I would like to know which usage is correct or if there are any specific instances in which each is used.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first is a little more casual than the second, and possibly found more in American English than in British English.

Comment: Hi Barrie. Could you please explain a bit more what you mean by _casual_?

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar: Informal, colloquial, not found in formal writing, used between close acquaintances. (It's not pejorative.)

Comment: I will wait a bit more before accepting this as the answer, just to see if there are any other explanations.

Comment: I would have said there's no difference in US English.

Answer (score 8):

"See you Monday" is more colloquial.  For instance, you would say to a friend "See you Monday!", but if you were making an appointment for something more formal it would be correct to say "See you on Monday".  The word "on" is implied in the less formal statement.