# (Presumably) an address without preposition

Tags: prepositions, british-english

I'm trying to translate a contract between two parties, and I came across this:

> Package and delivery Dual Gadgets, Kempston, Beds UK as defined in TERMS 2001.

and

> **Delivery Point**
>
> The Equipment shall be ready Dual Gadgets, Kempston, Bedford UK 4 weeks after The Seller has received a confirmed order / contract and the deposit payment.

What does that mean? Why is there no preposition? Does it mean that "it will be delivered *to* Dual Gadgets, Kempston, Beds, UK" or does it mean that "it will be delivered *by*" them? Or some other meaning that I can't get?

Comment: I'd lean toward "delivered to", though "delivered by" is a plausible interpretation. Neither strike me as good English. If you're in doubt over the details of a contract, I'd advise you to clarify with the source of the contract; a perfectly well-argued answer on a website about the English language will serve you little good if you have a legal problem.

Comment: I just wanted to see if it's proper use first, before investing further. It's an interesting mistake though, considering the fact that the company is from the UK.

Comment: Contracts tend to have a lot of heavy elision, and ironically a lot of heavy redundancy. To paraphrase a judge in a rather amusing case, "it is not graceful English but you must pretend that it is and then answer it, otherwise we will be here for ever." In this case, it's not that the elision is *wrong* so much that it's not terribly useful as eliding from "delivery to" and "delivery by" have equal results. Unless something else means the meaning clear. I *would* strongly lean towards the "delivered to" interpretation, but not so much as to bet not getting sued on it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. To the downvoter: why the downvote, am I violating a rule by asking this question?

Comment: @hattenn: I've only just this minute cast my downvote, which I'll explain by saying the question is Too Localised. Clearly the "sentence" is already "ungrammatical" by the time we reach the third word, so it seems a bit pointless to worry about more grammar problems further in. Also, since you haven't given the *rest* of the "sentence", it's impossible for us to know whether Dual Gadgets is the supplier or the customer. But presumably you *do* have the rest of the context, in which case the answer to that question should be blindingly obvious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers there could well be a wider question in the specific example. I agree with the rest you have to say, bar that it may not be obvious from context what Dual Gadgets' role in this is (though it certainly may be), but that doesn't mean we wouldn't have a wider question out of these specifics. Alas, I don't think anyone can provide a clear answer, but that's another matter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have just edited my question, added the rest of the sentences (and mind you, the sentences end the way I've written - as they are individual articles -, they don't continue with another sentence). I just wanted to find out (hopefully from a native speaker) if this was a proper usage that I'm not aware of (I don't have much experience with legal texts). And the fact that this is British English, made me question myself more as I'm more accustomed to American English. So in light of the edit, could you give me my "blindingly obvious" answer now?

Comment: @hattenn: You still haven't really given the full context (do you have it? if not, why are you trying to interpret a fragment?), but my guess is Dual Gadgets is in fact "The Seller" - that address in Beds just happens to be one of their distribution points, and they're saying they'll have the goods ready ***there*** at the appointed time (for customer collection, or to be sent from there on/after that date by a delivery firm or one of their own lorries). As to the missing preposition, it's no different to [See you Monday](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48621/)

Comment: The suspicious (not me, of course) might surmise that obscurantism in statements such as the above (not, of course, in this actual case) is designed to avoid legal responsibilities. However, 'TERMS 2002' (assuming the company involved had such a document, which is probably a legal requirement) (and a microscope) might make things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read it as 'ready *at* Dual Gadgets', which is effectively the same as 'delivered to'.  It looks as if the draftsman has been unduly influenced by such phrases as 'fob [or free on board] Southampton', where *any* preposition would be frowned on or even mistaken.

Comment: Yes, this: the Delivery Point defines the place of delivery much like you would define the *terms* of delivery with a term of art such as "EXW Dual Gadgets" (*ex works*). This style of business English is a bit like headline English.