# What preposition used to say "monday morning"

Tags: prepositions

I want to say we have the weekly meeting on monday morning
Im not very clear with the preposition is it
1)on monday morning
2)at monday morning
3)any other

Thank you

Comment: Go with "on Monday morning".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["See you Monday" vs "See you on Monday"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48621/see-you-monday-vs-see-you-on-monday)

Answer (score 3):

When You want speak about date You have to use **on**.

> I ski on Monday.

When You want speak about times You have to use **at**.

> I wake up at 08:00AM.

[image]

Watch this [video.](http://www.engvid.com/prepositions-how-to-use-in-at-and-on-in-english/)

Comment: Note the phrase: "on the hour" which disobeys the rules.